# How to block all pop ups using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to block all pop ups using webdriver+java? I know how to handle pop ups but i don't want pop up at all, i want to block all the pop ups just like a pop up blocker in a browser...

Comment: My question is I don't want to see pop up at all while testing, so what can we do here is we need to turn pop up blocker on manually using Firefox settings, I need to know is there any other way to turn on the pop up blocker pro grammatically...

Comment: Why all the hate? After a bit of digging, I *think* Firefox (even in Selenium) blocks popups by default. The problem might be that there are more sophisticated pop-ups now, so unless you turn JS, flash, etc off entirely...

Answer (score 5):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("dom.popup_maximum", 0);
profile.setPreference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", false);
FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
fd.get("http://example.com");
```

Comment: `false` should be `False`

Comment: Code executes, and properties are modified according to about:config, but popups still open for me on Firefox 60, geckodriver 0.23.0, selenium 3.141.0, Debian 9. But I am using Python.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("privacy.popups.disable_from_plugins", 3)
```

to block all plugin popups.

See https://superuser.com/questions/697018/how-to-disable-popups-in-firefox-without-add-ons for other options.

Comment: Sorry just realized you said Java. This is Python but there must be something similar.