# How to block ads in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to run script new tab of ad getting opened every time, how we can restrict this ads or by closing that tab continue with out script.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201949/how-to-block-all-pop-ups-using-webdriver